# Subtracting Pandas Data Frame with another of different size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to assigin a new Colunm ['minIndx'] to a DataFrame.

Each row in DataFrame df2, would be taken to find a ManHatton Distance with DataFrame df and the index of df which is least distant from row of df2 is said to be minIndx for df2 's row

## The below line of code works very fast:

```
#df.loc[2] is assumed to be one row of df1
k=df-df.loc[2] # Second Row 
k.abs().sum(axis=1).idxmin()
# out put in few secounds
```

## But Below Code Runs for ever

```
def find_minIndx(row):
    k=df-df.row 
    return k.abs().sum(axis=1).idxmin()
df_2=df_2.head(1) # Testing For one Row
df_2['minIndx']=df_2.apply(find_minIndx)
```

Why is the second code taking too much of time, How to Fix it ?

Comment: Because in second code snippet, you are doing it for every row!

Comment: And you create a new Series for each row

Comment: @harvpan Even for One Row it was stuck.. Thanks for your comments, I Edited the code to reflect what you pointed out

Comment: @Jonas Please help me with a snippet  of code to understand it better

Comment: For rows you should use df_2.apply(find_minIndx, axis=1)

Comment: Thanks @Jonas let me Try that and Would accept the answer if worked

Comment: @Jonas Please drop that in the answer... It worked ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rows you should use df_2.apply(find_minIndx, axis=1)